# Guest bulk questions

Tags: social-tables

We’re trying to get an understanding of the guest bulk api endpoints, and have some questions we need to get clarified.

1. Can you please provide examples to the guest bulk import? Does a batch update return the social tables internal guest id?
2. How do we add gender to a guest in the bulk import in order to use them in the auto seating function?
3. How do we add tags on guests in the guest bulk api?
4. The guest bulk import create method seem to support custom id on each guest, are there any requirements on how we build these ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a POST to /4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests/_bulk to create guests, a sample body with tags could be:

```
{
    action: "CREATE", 
    guests: [
            {"first_name": "Test", "last_name": "One", "tags": ["VIP", "Donor"]},
            {"first_name": "Test", "last_name": "Two"}
    ]
}
```

1. A bulk update request will not return any data, but if you fetch the guestlist after your update, you will have all the guests' data including internal guest id.
2. Gender is not a supported property by default for guests at this time. If you wish, you may add it as a property by creating it as a Custom Field on guests after import.
3. See code sample for importing guests with tags.
4. The bulk endpoint does indeed support user-generated guest ids. There are no requirements for these ids, but you are responsible for guaranteeing uniqueness among the ids.

Comment: In which scope does the guest id need to be unique? Within your entire guest database or within the events guestlist scope?

Comment: Is there a max limit on how many guests you can do CRUD operations on in the bulk endpoints?

Comment: The scope for uniqueness on guest id is only within the event guestlist, not the entire guest database. There is no max limit on the number of guests you can operate on through the bulk endpoints.